# xBim ifc manipulation: Trying to add a property set

Tags: properties, ifc, xbim

I'm trying to manipulate an ifc2x3 file with xBim. It's based on the example: https://docs.xbim.net/examples/basic-model-operations.html

But when it comes to `var pSetRel = model.Instances.New<IfcRelDefinesByProperties>`, 
it crashes with `System.Exception: "This factory only creates types from its assembly"`
Here is the code:

```
string fileName = modelsPath + "Duplex_A_20110907.ifc";

using (var model = IfcStore.Open(fileName))
{
    //get existing wall from the model
    var id = "2O2Fr$t4X7Zf8NOew3FNld";
    var wall = model.Instances.FirstOrDefault<IfcWall>(d => d.GlobalId == id);

    //open transaction for changes
    using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Walls modification"))
    {
        //create new property set with two properties
        var pSetRel = model.Instances.New<IfcRelDefinesByProperties>(r =>
        {
            r.GlobalId = Guid.NewGuid();
            r.RelatingPropertyDefinition = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertySet>(pSet =>
            {
                pSet.Name = "New property set";
                //all collections are always initialized
                pSet.HasProperties.Add(model.Instances.New<IfcPropertySingleValue>(p =>
                {
                    p.Name = "First property";
                    p.NominalValue = new IfcLabel("First value");
                }));
                pSet.HasProperties.Add(model.Instances.New<IfcPropertySingleValue>(p =>
                {
                    p.Name = "Second property";
                    p.NominalValue = new IfcLengthMeasure(156.5);
                }));
            });
        });

        //change the name of the door
        wall.Name += "_checked";
        //add properties to the door
        pSetRel.RelatedObjects.Add(wall);

        //commit changes
        txn.Commit();
    }

    model.SaveAs(modelsPath + "/Duplex_A_20110907_modified.ifc");
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the `using` statements, but I would guess that you're referencing the Ifc4 version of `IfcRelDefinesByProperties` rather than the Ifc2x3 equivalent.

You can't mix & match the schema entities.

Comment: thanks I got it to work by using the ifc2x3 namespace

Answer (score 0):

You need to be carefull when selecting the types of objects you are using, you need to assure that you select always the type that corresponds to your IFC Schema, for example:

[xBIM example of selecting the right type of IFC schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knQpx.png)